# Android: How can I use Mock on both test code?

Tags: android, testing, junit

I am developing an android app using "Android Jetpack WorkManager".

My presenter code uses it.

I want to test my presenter code.

First I tried to use the JUnit test, but because of WorkManager, I am changing it to AndroidTest.
Below is my build.gradle.

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19'
}
```

In this case, I cannot use "Mock" in my AndroidTest code.
So I changed the dependency like:

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19'
}
```

Then, I cannot use "Mock" in my JUnit test code.
So I tried:

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19'
}
```

This doesn't work too...

How should I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: mockito-android

```
dependency {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-android:2.25.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to Mock android components you can use the Robolectric to do that on your unit tests.